# How to get the sum of salaries from a multidimentional array after condition

Tags: php, html, arrays, if-statement, foreach

In this project i have a multidimentional array that keeps some employees names, their position, their speciality and their salary. I need to find the average salary of all the managers and all the employees from the array.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta sharset="UTF-8"/>
<title>Project3</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$employees = array(array("name" => "Nikolaou Nikolaos",
                         "occupation" => "Employee",
                         "salary" => 1500,
                         "specialty" => "Web Programmer"),
                   array("name" => "Papadopoulou Anna",
                         "occupation" => "Manager",
                         "salary" => 2300,
                         "specialty" => "Human resources management"),
                   array("name" => "Alexiou Nikoleta",
                         "occupation" => "Employee",
                         "salary" => 800,
                         "specialty" => "Secretary"),
                );

//Start of the function that prints the arrays in a specific way.
function printTable($table) 
{   
    foreach ($table as $employee => $list) {

        // Print a heading:
        echo "<h2 style=\"text-align:left; font-size:26px; font-family:times new roman; color:blue\">Employee #$employee</h2><ul>";

        // Print each district data:
        foreach ($list as $key => $value) {
            echo "<li style=\"text-align:left; font-size:18px; font-family:times new roman; color:black\">$key: $value</li>\n"; 
        }// End of nested FOREACH.

        // Close the list:
        echo '</ul>';

    } // End of main FOREACH.
}// End of the function.

//function that calculates and returns the average salary of employees and managers separately.
function calcMeanAges($table, &$hmean, &$gmean) 
{
    $cEmployees = 0;
    $sumsalary_e = 0;
    $cManagers = 0;
    $sumsalary_m = 0;
    foreach ($table as $occupation =>$list) {
        foreach ($list as $salary =>$value) {
            if ($occupation == "Employee") {
                $cEmployees++;
                $sumsalary_e += $salary['salary'];
            }
            if ($occupation == "Manager") {
                $cManagers++;
                $sumsalary_m += $salary['salary'];
            }
        }
    }
    $hmean = $sumsalary_e / $cEmployees;
    $gmean = $sumsalary_m / $cManagers;
}

//call of the function that calculates the average salaries.
calcMeanAges($employees, $h, $g); 
echo "$h<br>";
echo "$g";

//Printing the elements of the arrays
echo '<p style="color:red;font-size:28px;font-family:times new roman;"><b>Employees and managers</b></p><br>';

printTable($employees);
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

I need to calculate the average salaries of employees and managers separately. So i thought of putting a condition in the `Foreach()` to check who is who and then count them and keep the sum of their salary. But it doesn't work properly. I would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0):

Basically:

To calculate the average sum up all different figures and then divide them through the total amount of figures.

So this part should be right.

Can you please check the datatypes of each from them:

$hmean = $sumsalary_e / $cEmployees;
$gmean = $sumsalary_m / $cManagers;

Every type should be an Integer or Int.

Answer (score 0):

You only need one loop not 2 in this case, then all the occurances you want to check or dd up are members of the inner arrays

```
function calcMeanAges($table, &$hmean, &$gmean) 
{
    $cEmployees     = 0;
    $sumsalary_e    = 0;
    $cManagers      = 0;
    $sumsalary_m    = 0;
    foreach ($table as $item) {
        if ($item['occupation'] == "Employee") {
            $cEmployees++;
            $sumsalary_e += $item['salary'];
        }
        if ($item['occupation'] == "Manager") {
            $cManagers++;
            $sumsalary_m += $item['salary'];
        }
    }
    $hmean = $sumsalary_e / $cEmployees;
    $gmean = $sumsalary_m / $cManagers;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this will proccess any occuption and calculate avarage salary. You can add an IF statment if you only need managers and Employee. You can leave it as be if at a later state other occuptions are added.

```
    $employees = array(
    array("name" => "Nikolaou Nikolaos",
        "occupation" => "Employee",
        "salary" => 1500,
        "specialty" => "Web Programmer"),
    array("name" => "Papadopoulou Anna",
        "occupation" => "Manager",
        "salary" => 2300,
        "specialty" => "Human resources management"),
    array("name" => "Alexiou Nikoleta",
        "occupation" => "Employee",
        "salary" => 800,
        "specialty" => "Secretary"),
);

function averageCount($employees)
{
    $count = [];

    foreach ($employees as $employee) {

        $occupation = $employee['occupation'];
        if (!array_key_exists($occupation, $count)) {
            $count[$occupation]['occupation'] = $occupation;
            $count[$occupation]['salary'] = $employee['salary'];
            $count[$occupation]['count'] = 1;
        } else {
            $count[$occupation]['salary'] += $employee['salary'];
            $count[$occupation]['count']++;
        }
    }
    if (count($count) > 0) {
        foreach ($count as $occupation => $item) {
            $count[$occupation]['average'] = $item['salary'] / $item['count'];
        }
    }

    return $count;
}

var_dump(averageCount($employees));
```